# TinyMCE: paste_enable_default_filters retain colors, img and font-size

Tags: tinymce, paste

Using TinyMCE 4.4. i like to get rid of pasted MS-Word-stuff. "**paste_enable_default_filters**" is a pretty tool for this. But i also like to prevent img, colors, font-size and -docorations on pasting. Since **paste_enable_default_filters = true** is set, **paste_data_images** and **paste_word_valid_elements** seems to be suppressed.

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The `Paste` plugin has many options to help you control what is pasted and what is removed:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/

In particular you may want to look at `paste_word_valid_elements`:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_word_valid_elements

...as this will allow you to control what tags are brought over during the paste.

You may also find value in `paste_retain_style_properties`:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_retain_style_properties

...as this will allow you to determine which styles should be retained during a paste.

If you want to have more control (beyond what the options on the `Paste` plugin perform) you can always use `paste_postprocess` to perform your own custom logic on the pasted content:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_postprocess

Comment: i've made a [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/S8faab) with these options. Pasteing mixed MS-Word-content will destroy "img", "color" and font-size. Setting **paste_enable_default_filters=false** I've got an expected result including MS-Trash in the textarea.

On **paste_postprocess** i've unsuccessful tried to delete html-coments <!--...-->. Any suggestion is welcome.